# Possible Code Improvement by Setting Integer Variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a test form with 2 bound combo boxes. I am testing the correct code to use so that the option selected on the first combo box affects the row source of the second combo box.

Combo box 1 is name of country. I assigned the control name as `cb_country`. I have also created a table `tbl_country` as row source for `cb_country`. The options are `China`, `Japan`, `Korea`, `Malaysia`, `Philippines`, and `Thailand`.

Combo box 2 is capital. I assigned the control name as `cb_capital`. I have created 2 different tables as possible row sources for `cb_capital` depending on which country was selected on `cb_country`.

Capital table 1 or `tbl_cap1` lists `Beijing`, `Tokyo`, and `Seoul` while capital table 2 or `tbl_cap2` lists `Kuala Lumpur`, `Manila`, and `Bangkok`.

I want the row source of `cb_capital` to be `tbl_cap1` whenever `China`, `Japan`, or `Korea` is selected and `tbl_cap2` whenever `Malaysia`, `Philippines`, or `Thailand` is selected.

Below is the `After Update` event code for `cb_country`.

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim fname As String
fname = "frmgeo"
Set frm = Forms(fname)

Dim n() As String
Dim co As Control
Dim ca As Control
n1 = "cb_country"
n2 = "cb_capital"
Set co = frm.Controls(n1)
Set ca = frm.Controls(n2)

Dim c() As String
c1 = "China"
c2 = "Japan"
c3 = "Korea"
c4 = "Malaysia"
c5 = "Philippines"
c6 = "Thailand"

If co = c1 Or co = c2 Or co = c3 Then
    ca = Null
    ca.Requery
    ca.RowSource = "tbl_cap1"
Else
    ca = Null
    ca.Requery
    ca.RowSource = "tbl_cap2"
End If
```

The form is working fine as I expected it to be but is there anyway that the code can be improved? Perhaps declaring an integer variable and using for-next statement since I use integers on variable names on this case?

Comment: I realized that I do not need to requery cb_capital when the code resets it to null.

Comment: Whenever you change RowSource, the control will requery, thus a separate Requery is not needed.

Comment: Why are contries and capitals not connect (each country has one capital)? A quiz?

Comment: It was just a test form that I demonstrated to my boss. I will add more controls to the actual form that I will demonstrate to the staff. Thank you, Unhandled Exception. The with end with statement is definitely useful in my actual form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I would do it, expecting the code is being executed in the form itself:

```
With Me.Controls("cb_capital")
    .Value = Null

    Select Case Me.Controls("cb_country").Value
        Case "China", "Japan", "Korea":
            .RowSource = "tbl_cap1"
        Case "Malaysia", "Philippines", "Thailand":
            .RowSource = "tbl_cap2"
        Case Else
            'Raise an error for example.
    End Select

    .Requery 'I also don't think that it is necessary.
End With
```

Some explanations:

- Because the code runs in the form which holds the controls, we can use `Me` to reference it.
- It's not always necessary to use explicit variables, you can use references in expressions as shown.
- The `With` statement holds the reference to the control `cb_capital` and you can access it by `.` in the `With` block.
- As long as you work with literals (the country names), you can directly use them in a `Select Case` statement. Regarding to your used logic you also could omit `Case "Malaysia", "Philippines", "Thailand":` and use just `Case Else` instead, if you want.
- Your array definitions `n()` and `c()` were not used at all. You used undecladred variables (`n1`, `n2`, `c1` - `c6`) instead. You should use `Option Explicit` in your modules to avoid that.

Comment: `tbl_cap1`and`tbl_cap2`strongly indicates a wrong db model, you should mention that.